# can't install edward2 a library in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, edward

I want to install edward2 library: https://github.com/google/edward2.
I used this command: `pip install "git+https://github.com/google/edward2.git#egg=edward2"`. But when I want to import it in spyder it had an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'edward2'.

Could someone help me to install it with conda?

Comment: Have you tried checking this project out with git clone? Can you provide a more detailed error message?

Comment: No, I havn't. Well I think pip can't build an environment in ananconda so when I try to import edward2 it says:  No module named 'edward2'

Comment: Do you have to use pip to check this project out? Are you checking out this project in a Unix based environment?

Comment: This procedure will help: 1.Open Anaconda Command prompt as administrator
2.Use cd\ to come out of set directory or path.
3.Run pip install command.